# ng-select - Data not loading correctly according to JSON

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ngselect

I am trying to load drop-down data using the below function. (using ng-select library)

```js
loadBranches() {
  this.registrationService.getBranchName().subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
     this.branchModel$ = data['data']['branchArr'];

  });
}
```

Currently, my console log data is loaded correctly. please check the below screenshot:

[image]

This is my HTML code.

```
<ng-select [items]="branchModel$ | async" bindLabel="branchName" required
    (change)="getBankInfo($event);" name="branchName" bindValue="title"
     placeholder="Select Branch" [(ngModel)]="reserve.branchName">
</ng-select>
```

but this approach did not work. Can you help me to load this drop-down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expect that `branchModel$` is `Observable<any[]>` type.

### Solution

Hence you need to cast your array as `Observable` with `of` rxjs operator.

```js
import { of } from 'rxjs';

this.branchModel$ = of(data['data']['branchArr']);
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-f2vzss)